# How to authenticate to Microsoft Exchange via the ExchangeWebServices Java API classes and OAuth?

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-msal

I have a working Java batch program accessing Microsoft Exchange via the
**ExchangeWebServices** Java API classes and the now **expired basic authentication**.
I want to the **change the authentication method to oauthentication** (package com.microsoft.aad.**msal4j**).
I found examples how to generate a ConfidentialClientApplication and then acquire a token (IAuthenticationResult) with it.
But then I don't know **how to create ExchangeCredentials out of the OAuth token** because the following line does not compile because **there is not class OAuthCredentials in the ExchangeWebServices**:

```
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
```

For Basic Auth I could simply use the following code:

```
ExchangeService     service     = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(<user>,<password>);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setUrl(new URI(<Exchange_URI>));
```

Now with msal4j for oauth I start as follows (example found elsewhere except for the last 2 lines):

```
IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(context.Exchange_AzureClientSecret);
ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
        ConfidentialClientApplication
                .builder(<Exchange_AzureClientId>, credential)
                .authority(<Exchange_Authority>)
                .build();
IAuthenticationResult authResult;
Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton("https://outlook.office365.com/.default");
     try {
         SilentParameters silentParameters =
                 SilentParameters
                         .builder(scope)
                         .build();
         // try to acquire token silently. This call will fail since the token cache does not
         // have a token for the application you are requesting an access token for
         authResult = cca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join();
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         if (ex.getCause() instanceof MsalException) {
             ClientCredentialParameters parameters =
                     ClientCredentialParameters
                             .builder(scope)
                             .build();
             // Try to acquire a token. If successful, you should see
             // the token information printed out to console
             authResult = cca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
         } else {
             // Handle other exceptions accordingly
             throw ex;
         }
     }
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
//...
```

How to create ExchangeCredentials out of the OAuth token (here named authResult)?

Answer (score 0):

The Official Java EWS Managed API isn't being updated or maintained by Microsoft anymore and doesn't support oAuth. Its open source and a few people have forked it and added that support in https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+oauth eg

https://github.com/bookaroom/RESTApi/blob/master/src/com/comeet/exchange/BearerTokenCredentials.java